# when exactly does a thread 'break'

Tags: c++, multithreading

First of all, I'm new to MT, so I apologise for any stupid/obvious things I might say :)

Let's say you have these thread callback functions for windows:

```
unsigned int __stdcall ThrdFuncA(void* param)
{
    std::wstring s(L"Hello World\n");
    std::wcout << s;
    return 0;
}

unsigned int __stdcall ThrdFuncB(void* param)
{
    std::wcout << L"Hello " << L"World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What I noticed is, when I ran ThrdFuncA with 4 threads at the same time, and re-running it 100 times, the output would always be

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

etc

but when I ran ThrdFuncB with 4 threads at the same time, and re-running it 100 times, the output would sometimes be

```
Hello WorldHello World

Hello World
Hello World
Hello WorldHello World

Hello World
```

But this raises questions, especially since the first version always works.
Does this mean that a thread never "breaks" when executing an external function, but always finishes that function? Is this OS specific?
When exactly will a thread "break"?

Comment: @Griwes I have, I didn't find any explanation regarding this matter in the articles I read. Feel free to downvote silently or help me on my way.

Comment: It did not, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: `since the first version always works` No, you made an invalid conclusion. You don't have even _nearly_ enough evidence to suggest "always"; in fact, you just got "lucky" because of the timing of the execution of that particular code.

Comment: Unsynchronised concurrent execution contexts aren't sequenced at all with respect to one another (hence "concurrent"). Everything you see is more or less a coincidence.

Comment: The first version surely has a lock - on the cout stream call.  his serializes the stream writes and prevents the complete string output in the first version from being 'split' by an interrupt and reentry from another thread.

Comment: Note: In C++11 (but not C++03) the standard guarantees there will be no internal data races (thus just means you can not break the stream). But it **does not** guarantee that your characters will not be interleaved so your assumption that `ThrdFuncA` always works is not correct. It is the responsibility of the application to provide mutual exclusive accesses to the resource (ie. The old C++ adage we do not want everybody to pay for an expensive operation (locking) that only a few people need so you must do it yourself).

Comment: @LokiAstari I still don't have any problems with the first version, all attempts I've made were successful. If you still claim that it won't always work, then please explain to me why the chances of failure are so extremely low?

Comment: @Griwes: drop the attitude, please. If a person has to learn the answer **before** asking questions here, SO is kind of useless. SO is intended as a source of information and answers, for newbies **as well** as experts.

Comment: @xcrypt: Because the number of times you have run are very small in comparison to the number of different processor/thread/event/signal combinations that are running in your system. Every swan I have ever seen is white. So why is the probability of me seeing a black swan so low?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preemptive threads - the sort that your C++ example has - break at whatever point they feel like.  So, it could be anything from coincidence up that shows the output you expect - more or less at random.

That is the nature of preemptive threads: you might be able to hint (with yield or some equivalent) that this is a good time to jump to another thread, and some operations might block and trigger another thread to run, but you can't ever determine when your thread might be switched away from.

In the much less common or popular cooperative threading systems, all switching is done at predictable times.  This is vaguely convenient, but it is easy for things to accidentally block thread switching when it would be nice, so they are not very much in favour.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear on what you mean by "break." On a truly parallel system with 4 processors (one for each of your threads) then the threads will never stop executing. Each thread is actively printing to a shared resource (in this case the output buffer) and it is very likely that the threads will write to the output buffer simultaneously, thus giving you interleaved output.

On a single core system, at any given moment, the operating system will stop one thread and run another thread. Since this can happen at any moment, the string data sent to the output buffer (the screen) can be in strange inter leavings.

Take a look at [mutual exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion). For a shared resource (std::cout), you can guard critical sections of code by requiring threads obtain a lock so that only one thread can access the resource at once. Locks are necessary for correctness in preemptive multithreaded system. See [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)

Comment: What if you have more threads running than you have cores? Then they would still break, right?

Comment: Yes, for simplification purposes I didn't mention that. In reality, even with four cores and four threads, the operating system and other background processes still need to run. The point is that your code should expect that any execution interleaving is possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a mutex lock on cout calls, so serializing them.  If you 'count' one complete "Hello World\n" string then the cout method core code will not be interrupted and reentered from another thread because of the lock. This results in unbroken output of the string.

If you make multiple calls with substrings and a newline, it's quite possible that another thread will get the lock in between the calls, so 'mixing up' the substrings and newline.

Comment: The standard does **not** guarantee this.

Comment: Maybe not, but the OP's output strongly suggests it!

Comment: No it does not. That is probably the worst assumption you can ever make (and will get people killed). It merely looks like he is getting lucky.

Comment: Look again!  'Hello', 'World' and 'CRLF' are not split anywhere in the OP's o/p.  Mixed up, just as if different threads are getting inside a lock, but not split and no characters are missing/corrupted.  What are the chances of that happening by chabnce, with no lock?  Note that I am not suggesting that this behaviour should be relied upon, just explaining the symptoms.

Comment: What are the chances. Quite high I would think.

Comment: Why is it that preemption occurs between the three calls?  The three little stream calls don't take so long that the threads making them are likely to be preempted often by a side-effect of some I/O or timer interrupt.  It's much more likely that the preemption is being instigated by the output call itself - by acquiring and releasing a lock.

Comment: **Complete fluke would be as good a reason as any other** (especially given your small sample size). Seeing patterns were there is none is what the human mind does. When you have run it 600 billion billion times and not seen a difference in output (and published it in a decent per-reviewed magazine) then we will be able to validate your claims after we have checked your methodology for flaws. Alternatively you could look through the source and tell me exactly where these locks are!

Comment: It is indeed possible that the results may be a fluke, but there is a pattern. The pattern I see is that three calls that copy small strings into a library stream buffer are being preempted much more often than I would expect from asynchronous hardware interrupts that would request a scheduler run.  I would expect the chance of an asynch preemption occuring in such a short length of code to be 'slim', and it's happening a lot.  Slim*slim*slim*slim*slim is, err.. 'very, very slim'.   One explanation is that the cout calls themselves are making an OS call that is prompting a scheduler run...

Comment: I think your understanding of probability and mine are different. I would say the output above is quite probable given the current program. Given the difficulty of **reproducing** problems and then ultimately tracking down a bug in multi threaded applications any assumptions are counter productive (because the debugging effort will be many orders of magnitude greater). Thus given there is possibility that you are wrong; no code review would ever let you make that assumption. The human mind has a tendency to see patterns where no exist and then invent rationalizations for the perceived patterns